# jquery addClass not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery

hello i made a code which required to add a class after the ajax call . I am sure the code is right but still the class is not being added . Its really strange as everything else in code works and i am sure the code for addClass is right also i have checked console for any errors but there are no errors . here is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.miclickks', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();

var for_uid    = $(this).parents("li").attr('data');
var for_name   = $(this).parents("li").attr('unme');
var for_pic    = $(this).parents("li").attr('upic');
var owner_uid  = $('.row-fluid').attr('uid');
var owner_name = $('.row-fluid').attr('usnm');
var owner_pic  = $('.row-fluid').attr('usp');
var type       = "kiss";

var dataString = "type=" + type + "&for_uid=" + for_uid + "&for_name=" + for_name + "&for_pic=" + for_pic + "&owner_uid=" + owner_uid + "&owner_pic=" + owner_pic + "&owner_name=" + owner_name; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "include/ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (html) {
            if(html=="300")
            {
            $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("Error Please Try Again.");

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
            else
            {
            $(this).addClass('active');     


            }
            }
        });



});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways:

***First***:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "include/ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (html) {
        if (html == "300") {
            $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("Error Please Try Again.");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        } else {
            $(that).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

***Second*** (use the `context` option):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "include/ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    context: this,
    success: function (html) {
        if (html == "300") {
            $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("Error Please Try Again.");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks all of you for the answer . well today i learned something new . It works perfect thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
var $p = $(this);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "include/ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (html) {
        if (html == "300") {
            $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("Error Please Try Again.");

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        } else {
            $p.addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `this` inside `success()` is the XHR object and not the clicked element. you can use the `context` option to force it to any value you want.

For ex:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this, // pass the clicked element via context
    ...
    success: function() {
       ...
       $(this).addClass('active'); // now this refers to the clicked element
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm saying something wrong and someone will correct, but I think that the error is in this instruction:`$(this).addClass('active');`
In this case 'this' refer to the ajax object, so be sure that your are calling the proprer object on which add the class active