# Can't show content immediately with ajax jquery

Tags: jquery

I have code like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a href='#' id='link1'>Link 1</a>
<div id='content'></div>
```

**Jquery-script:**

```
$("a#link1").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        data: ...,
        type: "post",
        url: ...,
        async: true,
        context: this,
        success: function (result1) {
            if (result1 == "ok") {
                $.ajax({
                    data: ...,
                    type: "post",
                    url: ...,
                    async: true,
                    context: this,
                    success: function (result2) {
                        $(this).next("#content").append(result2);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**My problem:**

- When i click a#link1 the content (result2) appended into div#content but **it not show immediately**, **it just show when i refresh(F5)** the page. Please help me let it show immediately!

Comment: Because i'm the new member, sorry about my format. Please help me fix it. Thanks!

Comment: There is a preview below the text box where you type your question, to show you how it looks formatted. If you notice that the question or code is not readable or not formatted as you expect, don't submit the question. Keep on formatting until it looks good. There is also a help button and a "How to format" box on the right of the text field. If you don't know how to format, read it!

Comment: I don't know if that's the only problem,  but inside the Ajax callback, `this` does not refer to the element. At the top of the event handler do `var $this = $(this);` and use `$this.next(...)...` inside the Ajax callback. See [jquery addClass not working after ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16634227/218196).

Comment: Felix Kling: it appended but it not show immediately, it's my problem. I want it show immediately. Thanks you help!

Comment: Well, Ajax requests take time.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with your internet connection speed. the ajax() is run asynchronously and you can't always get an immediate response since a distant website is queried (specified in url parameter)

Even facebook uses the (Loading) modal window when performing some operations with ajax